# Make Picturebox Bounds "collision" add to score Label

Tags: c#, winforms

Trying to make a simple C# program where a ship goes through several "checkpoints" and when it's bounds interesect, it adds to the players score, then game ends when you reach the final checkpoint. Can't figure out how to make the score go up and print to the label each time. Thanks!

**UPDATE**: I can get my boxes to increase the score once, but not on all the other pictureboxes. Also, when I hit the final "spaceport" picturebox I get stuck in a messagebox redirect loop. How do I solve these 2 things? Tutors at school are no help.

```
public partial class consoleForm : Form
{
    public consoleForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void consoleForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void outputBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int score = (0);
        if (ship.Bounds.IntersectsWith(wormhole1.Bounds))
    {
        score += (1);
        userScore.Text = score.ToString();
        this.Refresh();
    }
    else if (ship.Bounds.IntersectsWith(wormhole2.Bounds))
    {
        score += (1);
        userScore.Text = score.ToString();
        this.Refresh();
    }
    else if (ship.Bounds.IntersectsWith(wormhole3.Bounds))
    {
        score += (1);
        userScore.Text = score.ToString();
        this.Refresh();
    }
    else if (ship.Bounds.IntersectsWith(wormhole4.Bounds))
    {
        score += (1);
        userScore.Text = score.ToString();
        this.Refresh();
    }
    if (ship.Bounds.IntersectsWith(spaceport.Bounds))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("you win");
        this.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: `yourLabel.Text = "Score: " + score;`

Comment: now i have it doing :                userScore.Text = score.ToString();

Comment: still isnt working. cant figure out how to check if the bounding boxes are touching

Comment: It might better to check the difference between the bounds of the ship and the wormholes/spaceport see if that difference is less than the size of the ship. If it is you have a collision. Also make sure you do it in an update event not the load event.

Comment: It's because you've only got the check for intersection on form load. This means it will run the code check only once, and never again until the form is re-loaded

Comment: The way it stands right now neither will work because your code is in the load event which is triggered when your form loads. Try putting it in a timer tick event and trigger the check every 100 ms

Comment: Also, from a standpoint of your game, you might want to ensure you're only adding to their score once for each collision going forwards. It probably wouldn't be very good if the player could quickly go back and forth across the bounds and rack up points.

Comment: I've posted an answer that shows you how to check the intersection "logic" periodically rather than on form load; but I must digress that (as everyone else has already stated), you need to tidy up the logic itself - but that's partially up to you :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem you've got is, that you're only doing this check *once* when the form loads, and never again.

Remove the logic from the `consoleForm_Load` event, and put it in your own method, called `CheckScore()`, or something else meaningful.

What would be good is to use a timer to check for the intersection every, let's say 100ms (0.1 seconds).

**Create a timer:**
In your constructor for the `consoleForm`, create a timer and a handler for it, then `Start` it. *You could even put it in your already-existing `consoleForm_Load` event - your choice :)

Like so:

```
public consoleForm()
{
    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(100); // Create a timer that fires every 100ms (0.1s)
    timer.Tick += OnTimer_Tick;
    timer.Start();
}
```

**Add an event for the `Tick` event of the timer:**

The `OnTimer_Tick` you can either "auto create" from VS, or add yourself:

```
private void OnTimer_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckScore(); // Call your logic method to check the score
}
```

**Do the logic:**

If you haven't already, make sure you've created the `CheckScore()` method using your original logic (that used to be in the `consoleForm_Load` event).

**Final note:**
I would seriously consider tidying up your `CheckScore()` (or whatever you like to call it) method, but that's just me :)

**Further final note**: *there are loads of other ways of creating timers; I'm just being nice and using the most basic use of a `Timer` in WinForms* :)

Hope this helps!

**MORE!!!**
At the moment, you're creating a new "score" every time you call the `CheckScore()` method.

In order to store your score, create a private field called `_score` or similar:

```
private int _score = 0;
```

Then, whenever you're adding to the user's score, reference the `_score` field, and use that to calculate and display:

```
_score++;
// or your own logic
_score += 20; // etc. etc.

// At the bottom of your logic,
// when you're ready to display the score:
userScore.Text = "Your score: " + _score;
```

Then, you can reference the `_score` wherever else you need it in your form.

Such as re-setting it:

```
private void ResetScore()
{
   _score = 0;
}
```

or checking if the score has reached a certain value:

```
public void CheckScore()
{
    ...
    // Your other logic to increment the score.
    ...

    if (_score >= 10) // Check if the score has reached a certain value.
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You reached 10 points! YOU WIN!");
    }
}
```

Bingo! ;)

Comment: RIGHT as you posted this I updated. Some things are working.... some are not. Thank you though this helped me understand it a lot better.

Comment: Always the way! I noticed you've put a timer on your form - also just as feasible. Like I've said, I will let you decide your actual logic, and what to do with it.

Comment: Right, I just am not sure why I'm unable to add extra digits to my score. I can only get it to hit 1 and no more, plus the whole winning messagebox thing

Comment: I've added to my answer on how to store the score and add to it etc. You can also check the value to show a message box if, say - the user's score is 10: `if (_score >= 10) { MessageBox.Show("You win!") }`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so your issue is that your only calling your code once - when the form is loaded. You need an update event set up and called regularly with the above code to make it work. Otherwise your code looks quite sound. Look into c# timers to get your update method called.